# Firebase Auth and Swift: Check if email already in database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an iOS app which will use Firebase for user management (sign up, sign in, etc.)

I'm new to Firebase, but it's mostly going ok. I've connected it, I have created users and logged in, etc.

But, I'm trying to change my UI so that the "Sign up" button is initially hidden and will only appear when:

1. all fields are not empty
2. email address is valid (using regex)
3. email address in not already in the database
4. user name is not already in the database
5. password and confirmPassword fields are equal

I can't figure out #3 and #4.

I've been reading documentation, watching videos, chasing links all over StackO and beyond, but I can't figure it out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you write email address and user name to firebase database?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [your attempt far](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and you'll be much more likely to receive answers that help you progress.  Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: @EmreCiftci Yes, I did. As I said in my question, I have successfully created users and logged in, so naturally, those two fields are in the database and have actual data.

Comment: @TobySpeight This is not the first time I've posted a question; so thanks for that link. This is a time when I *simply can't find anything to try*. Perhaps if you read my question, you'll note that I've researched this quite a bit and I can't find anything to help me with this. You want to see my "attempt far"? So shall I simply post the links to the dozens of YT videos, Firebase docs and tutorials, and other articles I've read that didn't help me get to where I want to be? Because that would seem truly useless: "Hey, guys, here's a bunch of things that didn't help."

Comment: The intention of this site is to help with specific and duplicatable coding issues. The problem with the question is there's not enough detail - any answer is just a guess which is why @TobySpeight asked to see the code so we could determine what type of authentication is being used. This is vague *user name is not in the database* where is the user name stored? In a /users node? Somewhere else? Is the user name the same as the email address? I posted an answer making a lot of assumptions, if it doesn't provide a solution, update the question with some more details and we'll take a look.

Comment: There are numerous questions on SO which are of the variety presented here: "I have a problem I'd like to solve. I can't figure out how to get started. Does anyone have any ideas?" That's what I have here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using email & password authentication, the solution is very simple.

Firebase Authentication will not allow duplicate emails so when the createUser function is executed, if the email already exists Firebase will return a [emailAlreadyInUse](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/AuthErrorCode#/c:@E@FIRAuthErrorCode@FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse) error in the error parameter. You can then cast this to an NSError to see which one it is and handle appropriately.

So the function is like this

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: createEmail, password: password ) { user, error in
   if let x = error {
      let err = x as NSError
      switch err.code {
      case AuthErrorCode.wrongPassword.rawValue:
         print("wrong password")
      case AuthErrorCode.invalidEmail.rawValue:
         print("invalid email")
      case AuthErrorCode.accountExistsWithDifferentCredential.rawValue:
         print("accountExistsWithDifferentCredential")
      case AuthErrorCode.emailAlreadyInUse.rawValue: //<- Your Error
         print("email is alreay in use")
      default:
         print("unknown error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
      }
      //return
   } else {
      //continue to app
   }
```

I threw some random errors into that case statement but check the link for a complete list of all AuthErrorCodes.

You can also do this

```
Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: user, completion: { (signInMethods, error) in
    print(signInMethods)
})
```

Comment: But, I'm trying to *pre-check*, ie, not allow the `createUser` to be called unless the criteria (eg, unique email address) are met. So, I'm hiding the "Sign Up" button and want to show it only when I already know that the email address is not in the database.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva You won't be able to do that unless you open up the node that stores email addresses to unauthenticated users, which would lead to anyone being able to read all users email addresses - and that's a spam issue obviously.

Comment: In the firebase documentation, I found a method in API Reference > JavaScript > firebase.auth > Auth called "fetchSignInMethodsByEmail". This apparently will return a list of signing methods for a particular email address or `nil` if none are found. This seems to be what I need, but...it's JavaScript.

Any ideas how to use this function? Do I need to write a Firebase Cloud Function? If so, how do I access that function from my Xcode/Swift/iOS app?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva Updated the answer. Give that a try.

Comment: Oooooooh, thanks! I'll try it! (Now, I just need to figure out how to get a value out of a closure.....)

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva You don't get a value out of a closure. You should build your app around working with the data within the closure as that's only when it's valid. For example, in this case, if you determine the email is not available, within the closure display a message in the UI stating so. In other words, let the closures control the flow of the app. If you try to use asynchronous closures in a synchronous way, it will cause issues and you will have invalid data.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is: I want a Boolean variable that is `true` if the email is in the Authentication list and `false` if it's not. The fact that this method uses a closure is annoying, because as you said, getting the value out of a closure is not straightforward. But, I did find an answer to that by defining my `Bool` outside the closure and referencing it with `self.` inside the closure. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva Yes, that's typically how it's done - lean on class variables to keep the data returned in a closure. After you've had time to evaluate it, if my answer helped you, please remember to accept it so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check it by using this method

```
   let ref1 = Database.database().reference().child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "UserName").queryEqual(toValue: "UserName enter by user")

        ref1.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (sanpshot) in

            print(sanpshot.exists()) // it will return true or false
        }
```

and same for email.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: This won't help with verifying the email address doesn't also exist (because you now have an *AND* clause) and this query cannot be run by unauthenticated users as the default rules won't allow it.